# How to differentiate two symbol copies

Tags: sketch-app, principle-app

In my Sketch wireframes, I'm using a list view of cards, with a single card being a Sketch symbol. To get a list view, I use multiple copies of this symbol on a screen.

When I import this into Principle, there is no differentiation between the individual cards, so a card on one screen transitions to a completely different position in the list view on another screen. Naming the symbols consistently between screens in Sketch doesn't help. Is there something I can do to match cards between two screens in Sketch?

Comment: When you want to make an interactive prototype in Principle from Sketch document it's all about naming layers. Principle fully relies on layers' names. This is the main difference between Principle and Flinto since in the latter app you can connect differently named layers. Btw, could you share your working file to take a look what's going wrong there?